# i want to use pickerview in segment control such that when i switch segments picker data also changes. here's my code:

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

//IBAction for segment control to change value in the label

```
@IBAction func changeValueSC(_ sender: Any) {
    
    switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        questionLabel.text = "HAS FOOD INTAKE DECLINED OVER THE PAST 3 MONTHS, DUE TO LOSS OF APPETITE, DIGESTIVE PROBLEMS, CHEWING OR SWALLOWING DIFFICULTIES ?"
        //[self, pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: 5, forComponent: 1)!] as [Any]
    case 1:
        questionLabel.text = "WEIGHT LOSS DURING THE PAST 3 MONTHS ?"
    case 2:
        questionLabel.text = "MOBILITY"
    case 3:
        questionLabel.text = "HAVE YOU SUFFERED PSYCHOLOGICAL STRESS OR ACUTE DISEASE IN THE PAST 3 MONTHS ?"
    case 4:
        questionLabel.text = "NUEROPSYCHOLOGICAL PROBLEMS"
        
    default:
        break
    }
    
}
```

//compulsory methods for pickerview

```
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{

    return 1   
}
```

//options1, options2 .....options5 are string type arrays

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    
    switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        return options1.count
    case 1:
        return options2.count
    case 2:
        return options3.count
    case 3:
        return options4.count
    case 4:
        return options5.count
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{
    
    
    
    switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        return options1[row]
    case 1:
        return options2[row]
    case 2:
        return options3[row]
    case 3:
        return options4[row]
    case 4:
        return options5[row]
    default:
        return ""
    }
    
}
```

when i'm changing the segment the label data is changing but no data is being displayed in the picker view

[screenshot of the view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfbNk.png)

Comment: i have the same solution as of Andreas Oetjen can you share your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the picker view that the data has changed and it should refresh some (or all) of it's components:

```
@IBAction func changeValueSC(_ sender: Any) {

    // ... same as before

    self.pickerView.reloadComponent(0)
    // or: reloadAllComponents()
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in function `numberOfRowsInComponent` and `titleForRow` to check if it's called?

Comment: i'm new to ios app development, don't know how to use breakpoints properly :/

Comment: You better find out... Did you set the delegate and data source?

Comment: crap ! i forgot to set the delegate ! reloadAllComponents helped too! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `changeValueSC` function you need to call `self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()`.